# list.files not showing text files with capital letter names?

Tags: r, list, text

I have the below code for retrieving text files from a specific folder on my computer:

```
MenthueFolder<-list.files(path = path.source, recursive = TRUE, pattern = "\\.txt$")
```

path.source is already specified to my working directory. The recursive part tells R to search through all subfolders until it finds .txt files (which is the pattern specification).

My name text files are in two formats: name##.txt and NAME##.txt.

I have managed to retrieve all lower case named text files but I cannot get the capital letter ones. Does anyone know if there is a parameter in the function I have to specify?

Thank you for all the help!

Comment: Is it safe to assume that this is a windows system on a windows drive?

Comment: This works fine on Linux: `setwd("/tmp"); system("touch name.txt; touch NAME.txt"); list.files(pattern="\\.txt")` →`[1] "name.txt" "NAME.txt"`.  As @r2evans hints, maybe you are going through some filesystem layer (such as a MacOS file system) that isn't case-sensitive?

Comment: It is a Windows drive indeed. What do you recommend I do?

Comment: (Assuming windows.) Windows' filesystem is case-insensitive with regards to file names. If I `echo "1" > name.txt` and then `echo "2" > NAME.txt`, then there is one file named `name.txt` that has `2` as its contents. In this case, both `file.exists("name.txt")` and `file.exists("NAME.txt")` will return `TRUE`, even though they really point to the same file.

Comment: Don't trust `file.exists(.)` here to tell you that there are both lower-case and upper-case variants of a filename. I don't know if it's possible to really create separate files with names different only in case; even if it is possible, I suspect that most (all?) utilities (using windows system32 filesystem calls) accessing that filesystem will be tricked, therefore unable to read one of the two files. If you really do have this case, I suggest you find a way to rename one of the two (does Windows Explorer see both?) to be unique regardless of case.

Comment: Is the problem really NAME.txt  or is it  NAME.TXT?    You might want to try adding  `ignore.case=TRUE`  to your `list.files` statement.

Comment: Thank you @r2evans! However, my NAME.txt files are called differently from my name.txt files. That is, one of the lower case file names is bvuac.txt whereas the upper case is called CHARD.txt

Comment: It is stil NAME.txt @G5W, but I will try ignore.case=TRUE

Comment: @G5W the ignore.case=TRUE parameter WORKED! Thanks for all the help everyone!

Comment: @Alex, please post an answer based on what you found out ...

Answer (score 0):

Answer: specify ignore.case=TRUE such as:

```
MenthueFolder<-list.files(path = path.source, recursive = TRUE, pattern = "\\.txt$", ignore.case = TRUE)
```